# XML Parser Returning unexpected token error and null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, xml-parsing

So I think I was questioning the wrong way in previous threads. I better put it like this.
I'm trying to parse the XML data:

```
<playlist>
<title>![CDATA[New Playlist]]</title>
<items>
<item>
<title>HAMD(LA ILAHA ILLALLAH)</title>
<description>Recited By :Alhaaj Muhammad Owais Raza Qadri -- Written By: Mufti-e-Azam Hind Molana Mustafa Raza Khan Noori</description>
<image>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~kanz/video/Images/9.jpg</image>
<startFromThis>true</startFromThis>
<duration>510</duration>
<source>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~kanz/video/flv/9.flv</source>
<sourceAlt>http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~kanz/video/mp4/9.mp4</sourceAlt>
<sourceType>direct</sourceType>
</item>
</items>
</playlist>
```

In my Activity, what I did was this but the logcat gives null pointer exception. Here's my Activity and below it the logcat error.

```
static final String URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~kanz/video/XML/9.xml";

// XML node keyse.
static final String KEY_SONG = "item"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_ARTIST = "description";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "image";
static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_SONG);

// looping through all song nodes <song>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String>();
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
    map.put(KEY_ARTIST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ARTIST));
    map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_THUMB_URL));
    map.put(KEY_DURATION, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DURATION));

    // adding HashList to ArrayList
    songsList.add(map);
}
```

Logcat gives Unexpected Token error and returns null which causes null pointer exception.

```
03-28 14:31:34.059: E/Error:(895): Unexpected token (position:TEXT ï»¿@1:4 in java.io.StringReader@40d220e0) 
03-28 14:31:34.080: I/System.out(895): null
03-28 14:42:59.560: D/AndroidRuntime(978): Shutting down VM
03-28 14:42:59.560: W/dalvikvm(978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.razatubevidurl/com.example.razatubevidurl.CustomizedListView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-28 14:42:59.639: E/AndroidRuntime(978): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I thought my previous question was vague and in this one, I tried my best to make the question clear and understandable.

Comment: where you are fetching xml content?

Comment: @Sajmon From the URL initialized to the variable URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's something about encoding. Maybe your parser doesn't like the exclamation mark (!). Can you make sure that you use the XML file with the correct encoding? (UTF-8)

Otherwise, you have this problem: [KXmlParser throws "Unexpected token" exception at the start of RSS pasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15254089/kxmlparser-throws-unexpected-token-exception-at-the-start-of-rss-pasing).

I googled around and it looks like the easiest fix is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736999/how-to-remove-bom-from-an-xml-file-in-java).
You can try adding this method. (From the tutorial you use, put this in the ImageLoader class.)

```
import java.io.PushbackInputStream;
private InputStream checkForUtf8BOMAndDiscardIfAny(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
PushbackInputStream pushbackInputStream = new PushbackInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), 3);
byte[] bom = new byte[3];
if (pushbackInputStream.read(bom) != -1) {
    if (!(bom[0] == (byte) 0xEF && bom[1] == (byte) 0xBB && bom[2] == (byte) 0xBF)) {
        pushbackInputStream.unread(bom);
    }
}
return pushbackInputStream; }
```

Then you can do

```
InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
is = checkForUtf8BOMAndDiscardIfAny(is);
```

I don't have a chance to test the method but it should do it.
Also, please see [Byte order mark screws up file reading in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java).

Comment: does the link you sent in the answer parse XML from server? Because mine is stored on the Server.

Comment: Yes, it's sent from a server. You can try creating a new local xml file with the same content and parse it.

Comment: @EnterLevelDev I think the problem you guessed right. But the solution you sent uses PullParser while I'm using XMLParser. Can you help me solve it with XMLParser?

Comment: @AbdusSamiKhan I'd love to but I don't have your full code that I can play with. Any of these helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java

Comment: check this link, it's my previous question and it has all the code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15656570/customized-list-view-android-catching-exception/15656735?noredirect=1#comment22233215_15656735

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27127/discussion-between-entryleveldev-and-abdus-sami-khan)

Comment: Thanks a lot, the single solution answer in my case